# Why aren’t my answers being seen?

Tags: discussion, comment, answers, review, voting

I’m a relatively new user on this site, and over the past 2-3 months, I’ve posted various answers to questions that were within my skill level to explain properly. My earlier answers were seen and reviewed by more experienced members, and I even garnered a few upvotes. However, I’ve noticed that in the past few weeks, my answers have gotten barely any attention in the form of comments, votes, or reviews. Do you have ideas about why this has been happening?

Comment: You're answering incredibly old questions?

Comment: Btw, fyi: many users hold answers to old questions to higher standards, i.e. the answer  must add something *significantly* novel beyond prior answers. If the answer does not, they may not upvote (or might even downvote). Further many users only browse questions in Newest order so they rarely see new answers to old questions.

Comment: Figuring out just what has changed on an old question is generally a pain in the keister, and in my experience is rarely worth the effort. If I see "Posted 7 years ago" at the top of a question, and the question itself isn't absolutely fascinating, I just close the tab.